# Bootstrap Image space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know how to add a space between the HTML image and the buttons [begin course and test]. Not sure if this is something I should do via my own CSS or a technique which can be done through bootstrap? I can't think of any clean solutions, only i.e. breaklines.

[image]

```
<div class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <img src="{% static 'images/image pathway here' %}" alt="HTML5" style="width:180px;height:140px;">

      <div class="btn-group btn-group">
         <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-default"> Begin Course </button>
        <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-default"> Test </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if its work, then use it anyway. Unless you find bug because of your breaklines. Or you can use margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to add a class to your button group, so it looks like so:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-top-spacing">
```

And then adding some custom CSS:

```
.btn-top-spacing{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```